# Node js and Mongo - Update object index inside array (I cant query with id)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to update an object inside an array by getting it's id and modifying the object. However I cannot seem to be able to get inside the object.
 If I search users by email and then use `$set` to update my object, all the other objects disappear.
There is no errors poping up, it just doesn't work.
If I try to get the object with a simple `findOne` it returns `null` even if I copy and paste the id from the mongo db
I have been trying to solve this for 5:30h and I haven't made any breakthrough. Please help me.

```
//my schemas
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProdcutSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    productDescription:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    pricePerUnit:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },

    productAmmount:{
        type:Number,
        required: true
    },

    /*productImagePath:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    }*/

});


const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name:{
        type: String,

    },

    email:{
        type: String,

    },

    password:{
        type: String,

    },

    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },

    products:[ProdcutSchema]
});


const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;

//My ajax (ajax is working fine, I get all the correct data onto the backend)
$.ajax({
                type: 'PUT',
                url: '/dashboard/' + productID,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType:'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    product_name        : productName,
                    price_PerUnit       : productPricePerUnit,
                    product_Description : productDscp,
                    product_Ammount     : productAmmount,
                }),
                success: getproducts()
            });

//Backend
//Update products
router.put('/dashboard/:id', (req, res)=>{
    const ID = req.params.id ;
    const {product_name, price_PerUnit, product_Description, product_Ammount} = req.body;           //Get access to ajax data using body parser

    if(!product_name || !price_PerUnit || !product_Description || !product_Ammount){
        res.send('Please fill out all fields with valid content');
    }else{
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(
            {_id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(ID)},                          //Find collection with same email as user
            { $set: {                          //Pull out index that matches id
                name:product_name,
                productDescription: product_Description,
                pricePerUnit: price_PerUnit,
                productAmmount: product_Ammount
            }  } ,
            (err) => {
                 if (err) console.log(err);

        })


    }



});
```

Note: I have tried doing `findOne` `findOneAndUpdate`, `findById`, and every other method.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use `findByIdAndUpdate` and pass object that contain the id instead of the I’d itself

Try this

```js
User.findByIdAndUpdate(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(ID),                          //Find collection with same email as user
            { $set: {                          //Pull out index that matches id
                name:product_name,
                productDescription: product_Description,
                pricePerUnit: price_PerUnit,
                productAmmount: product_Ammount
            }  } ,
            (err) => {
                 if (err) console.log(err);

        })
```